# how to convert ManageIQ application development mode to production mode which will generate production log instead of development log

Tags: ruby, development-environment, production-environment, manageiq

how to convert ManageIQ application development mode to production mode which will generate production log instead of a development log.

> "ManageIQ production Environment"

Comment: Try to provide some code, to show what you've done before.
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: just git cloned manageiq and did some updation on it and now want to run it in production mode to improve performance(increase working speed)

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: `bundle exec rake evm:start RAILS_ENV=production`

but ManageIQ is quite a complex piece of software, so I advice you to read docs very carefully: http://manageiq.org/docs/guides/developer_setup.html